# Postgresql index and seq scan

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm realised that one interesting thing. I have a table with multiple column index.

```
CREATE INDEX transaction_idx ON transaction USING btree (period_id, day_id, value_type, indicator_id);
```

when I run query like :

```
select *
from transaction
where  period_id = '202104'
and day_id = 30
and  value_type = 1
and indicator_id = 2
```

DB will go seq scan.

But if I just change the day_id value to 20, then DB will go Index Scan.
Go index Scan
[image]

Go Seq Scan
[image]
I'm appreciate that if someone can share the root reason to me about it .

Thank you !

Comment: can you show the structure of your table (`CREATE TABLE transaction ...`) and especially the data type of the column day_id ?

Comment: Hi @Edouard H. thank you for your comment, I've just solved this issue and share my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've updated the random_page_cost value, the query is run as my expectation.

```
alter database db set random_page_cost=0.7;
```

Comment: That solution is probably the wrong one, since random I/O won't be cheaper than sequential I/O. It may ruin the execution plans for other queries. Perhaps your statistics are off, or other parameters are set wrongly. Hard to see with the obfuscated cut-off images you show instead of formatted text.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, Thank you for your reply and share your concern.  I'd like to  explain it more clearly.
We are using SSD disk, the I/O performance is better than HDD. And the minimum table size in same database is around 20 million records and keep increasing 200k per day.  That's reason we hope all queries should go index scan instead of sequence scan

Comment: I see. It's a dangerous bargain though - sometimes a sequential scan is the most efficient strategy.

Comment: Hi Laurenz,  if you don't mind, could share some of postgresql query optimisation to us ? When should we use seq scan, and what is right random_page_cost number should set ? like seq scan will work for small table and index scan should work for big table.

Comment: I shared some ideas in my first comment. Yes, for small tables, a sequential scan is the right thing. Also if you have a `WHERE` clause that only filters out few rows.